# Record Not Added using JavaFx

Tags: java

i creating a simple crud using JavaFx.while add the record into the database record not addedd.i am a beginner of Java Fx. i wrote the complete code below.what i tried so far.this is the first time i am using javafx anything wrong with code.if there is anything wrong please tell me

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

      @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private Button btnAdd;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtnum1;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtnum2;

    @FXML
    private TextField phone;

    @FXML
    private Label lab;


    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;




    public void Connect()
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/addressbook ", "root","");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

        }   
    }


    String num1 = txtnum1.getText();
    String num2 = txtnum2.getText();
    String phonee = phone.getText();

    @FXML
    void display(ActionEvent event) {

          try {
              pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into records(name,address,phone)values(?,?,?)");
              pst.setString(1, num1);
              pst.setString(2, num2);
              pst.setString(3, phonee);

            int i = pst.executeUpdate();

            if(i==1)
            { 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Addedd!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Addedd Failed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }

          } catch (SQLException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
    }
```

**Stacktrace i posted below**:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/kobinath/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication2/dist/run1228984529/JavaFXApplication2.jar!/javafxapplication2/FXMLDocument.fxml:10
```

Comment: which of the message dialogs is shown? Or what exception is caught? Which methods are the lines `String num1 = txtnum1.getText(); ...` in?

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: why don't you post the stracktrace? we cannot guess what is wrong.

Comment: i am entering only string values

Comment: how to post it sir

Comment: connect method called is correct

Comment: i have posted ....